# How resolve a error that a subquery is not introduced with EXISTS?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run my query but I get an error.

This is my query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
          F.FORN_ID,
          F.FORN_COD,
          F.FORN_DESC,
          FORN_CEP,
          FORN_CNPJ,
          F.PAIS_COD,
          F.REGI_COD,
          (SELECT TOP 1 CONT_NOME FROM CONT_CONTATOS WHERE CONT_PRINCIPAL = 1 AND SEGM_COD = @SEGM_COD AND CONT_INATIVO = 0 AND FORN_ID IN(SELECT FORN_ID FROM FORN_FORNECEDORES WHERE MSTR_ID = F.FORN_ID)) AS CONT_NOME,
          (SELECT TOP 1 CONT_EMAIL FROM CONT_CONTATOS WHERE CONT_PRINCIPAL = 1 AND SEGM_COD = @SEGM_COD AND CONT_INATIVO = 0 AND FORN_ID IN(SELECT FORN_ID FROM FORN_FORNECEDORES WHERE MSTR_ID = F.FORN_ID)) AS CONT_EMAIL,
          (SELECT TOP 1 SEGM_COD FROM CONT_CONTATOS WHERE CONT_PRINCIPAL = 1 AND SEGM_COD = @SEGM_COD AND CONT_INATIVO = 0 AND FORN_ID IN(SELECT FORN_ID FROM FORN_FORNECEDORES WHERE MSTR_ID = F.FORN_ID)) AS SEGM_COD,
          (SELECT FORN.* FROM FORNECEDORES_PERFIL as FORN 
                LEFT JOIN PERF_PERFIL as PERFIL 
                ON FORN.PERF_COD = PERFIL.PERF_COD
                LEFT JOIN FAB_FABRICA as FAB ON FORN.FAB_COD = FAB.FAB_COD
                LEFT JOIN TIPO_FABRICAS as TIPO_FAB ON FORN.TP_FAB_COD = TIPO_FAB.TP_FAB_COD
              WHERE FORN_ID = F.FORN_ID
          ) AS PROFILE,
          --C.CONT_NOME,
          --C.CONT_TEL,
          --C.CONT_TEL2,
          --C.CONT_CEL,
          --C.CONT_EMAIL,
          --C.SEGM_COD,
          F.FEIR_COD,
          FE.FEIR_DESC,
          F.CREATE_DATE,
          F.FORN_STATUS,
          F.USU_COD,
          (SELECT COUNT(CONT_ID) FROM CONT_CONTATOS WHERE CONT_PRINCIPAL = 1 AND SEGM_COD = @SEGM_COD AND CONT_INATIVO = 0 AND FORN_ID IN(SELECT FORN_ID FROM FORN_FORNECEDORES WHERE MSTR_ID = FORN_ID)) AS COUNT_CONT_PRINCIPAL,
          F.PLAT_ID,
          F.MSTR_ID,
          F.CODE,
          (SELECT SEGM_COD FROM FORNECEDORES_FAVORITOS WHERE SEGM_COD = @SEGM_COD AND FORN_ID = F.FORN_ID) AS FAVORITES,
          (SELECT COUNT(NOTA_ID) FROM NOTA_NOTAS WHERE SEGM_COD = @SEGM_COD AND TP_NOTA_ID = 2 AND NOTA_INATIVA = 0 AND OBJ_ID = F.FORN_ID) AS NOTA_COUNT,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY F.FORN_ID) AS LINHA,
  F.UPDATE_DATE
      FROM FORN_FORNECEDORES F
      LEFT OUTER JOIN FEIR_FEIRAS FE (nolock) ON FE.FEIR_COD = F.FEIR_COD
      --LEFT OUTER JOIN END_ENDERECOS E ON E.FORN_ID = F.FORN_ID
      --LEFT OUTER JOIN CONT_CONTATOS C ON C.FORN_ID = F.FORN_ID AND C.CONT_PRINCIPAL = 1 AND C.CONT_INATIVO = 0
      WHERE (F.FORN_DESC like '%'+@FORN_DESC+'%' or @FORN_DESC IS NULL)
          AND (F.FEIR_COD = @FEIR_COD or @FEIR_COD IS NULL)
          AND (F.FORN_ID = @FORN_ID or @FORN_ID IS NULL)
          AND (F.FORN_STATUS = @FORN_STATUS or @FORN_STATUS IS NULL)
          AND (F.USU_COD = @USUARIO_ID OR @USUARIO_ID IS NULL)
          AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),F.CREATE_DATE,102) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CREATE_DATE_I,102)or @CREATE_DATE_I IS NULL)
          AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),F.CREATE_DATE,102) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CREATE_DATE_F,102) or @CREATE_DATE_F IS NULL)
  AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),F.UPDATE_DATE,102) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@UPDATE_DATE,102)or @UPDATE_DATE IS NULL)
          AND FORN_INATIVO = 0
          AND F.FORN_ID = F.MSTR_ID
    `
```

the error is exactly when I added this sub query

```
      (SELECT FORN.* FROM FORNECEDORES_PERFIL as FORN 
            LEFT JOIN PERF_PERFIL as PERFIL 
            ON FORN.PERF_COD = PERFIL.PERF_COD
            LEFT JOIN FAB_FABRICA as FAB ON FORN.FAB_COD = FAB.FAB_COD
            LEFT JOIN TIPO_FABRICAS as TIPO_FAB ON FORN.TP_FAB_COD = TIPO_FAB.TP_FAB_COD
          WHERE FORN_ID = F.FORN_ID
      ) AS PROFILE,
```

I observed some random questions but none of them worked, I even tried to add FORN.* but without success

This error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: The error message is very concise, SQL Server is expecting the sub-query to return a single row; this question is asked very frequently and has many answers both on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: All those subqueries with a `TOP (1)` and no `ORDER BY` have a code smell to them. Without an `ORDER BY` the data engine is free to return an arbitrary value, and that value could be different *every time* you run the query.

Comment: but I would like it to return all data from the subquery query and not just the TOP 1

Comment: Then you don't want a subquery, you want a `JOIN` (or `APPLY`). When using a subquery in the `SELECT` like this, it can only return a **scalar** value; that's a *single* value. One column with one row of data.

Comment: but the main query returns a list, and each row executes a subquery,  right?

Comment: Yes, and for each row the subquery returns a **scalar** value. Though, again, with that many subqueries, I would also suggest that what you want is a `JOIN`/`APPLY`. All those subqueries aren't going to be efficient as, as you mentioned, they are executed *once per row*. A `JOIN`/`APPLY` would likely be executed once for the *set*.

Comment: For the sake of understanding this behaviour you can think of `select` like an iterator over the data made available in `from`. It says "for each row available in the `from` clause, this is the data I actually want". Therefore one of the items in your `select` can't have multiple rows, because how can you populate a row with multiple rows?

Comment: but i will execute APPLY how SUBQUERY or in the clausule WHERE?

Answer (score 3):

It's this subquery in the `SELECT` clause:

```
 (SELECT FORN.* FROM FORNECEDORES_PERFIL as FORN 
        LEFT JOIN PERF_PERFIL as PERFIL 
        ON FORN.PERF_COD = PERFIL.PERF_COD
        LEFT JOIN FAB_FABRICA as FAB ON FORN.FAB_COD = FAB.FAB_COD
        LEFT JOIN TIPO_FABRICAS as TIPO_FAB ON FORN.TP_FAB_COD = TIPO_FAB.TP_FAB_COD
      WHERE FORN_ID = F.FORN_ID
  ) AS PROFILE,
```

Each item in the `SELECT` clause is only allowed to have **ONE** value. However, the subquery returns `FORN.*`, which is *many values*. If you really want to include every column from the subquery in the results, you may try using an `APPLY` lateral join instead.

Comment: Maybe add on an example of using `APPLY`